# Print results of multiple SQL queries as one result

Tags: mysql

So I have 3 SQL query results (example code below). I want the results to be displayed either as different columns or different tables. Is this even possible? If yes, please help as to how. The results are unrelated to each other

```
SELECT RouterName, RouterType, Loopback100, Loopback200, ResiliencyGroup, 
DeploymentStatus 
FROM Routers
WHERE RouterName = 'PE23-SNG-AP'


SELECT ARouter, AInterface, BRouter, BInterface 
FROM netplan.LinksPACSLcl
WHERE ARouter = 'PE23-SNG-AP' OR Brouter = 'PE23-SNG-AP'
```

Comment: as it is it is returning as different result set. what do you want ?

Comment: So are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't just add tags to draw more attention to the question; the solution might be different based on the RDBMS you use.

Comment: Apologies on adding sql-server, now removed

Comment: @Squirrel, I want the result sets to be concatenated (for lack of better word?) next to each other.

Comment: oh `MySQL`, sorry... i am out of here

Answer (score 0):

This is, I believe, a job for JOIN. With respect if you don't know about JOIN you should study it; it's a core feature of SQL. It combines rows from multiple tables into single output rows.

Try something like this

```
SELECT i.RouterName, i.RouterType, i.Loopback100, i.Loopback200, 
       i.ResiliencyGroup i.DeploymentStatus, 
       j.ARouter, j.AInterface, j.BRouter, j.BInterface
  FROM Routers i 
  LEFT JOIN netplan.LinksPACSLcl j (ON i.RouterName = j.ARouter
                                    OR i.RouterName = j.BRouter)
 WHERE RouterName =  'PE23-SNG-AP'
```

This generates a result set with the items from both your first and second tables, assiging the alias names `i` and `j` to those tables. The LEFT JOIN operation allows information from the first table to be shown even without anything matching it in the second table.

Comment: This happens to work the same way in MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNION. This is a working sample. The important part is Column names. Check carefully the usage of **col1** with **as**

```
select UserName as col1 from Users
union
select FeatureName as col1 from Features
union
select TopicName as col1 from Topics
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a json result ;)

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$',
       JSON_EXTRACT((SELECT concat('[', 
                      group_concat(
                       JSON_OBJECT('RouterName'      , `RouterName`, 
                                   'RouterType'      , `RouterType`,
                                   'Loopback100'     , `Loopback100`,
                                   'Loopback200'     , `Loopback200`,
                                   'ResiliencyGroup' , `ResiliencyGroup`,
                                   'DeploymentStatus', `DeploymentStatus`) 
                                   SEPARATOR  ','),
                                   ']')
                       FROM Routers
                      WHERE RouterName = 'PE23-SNG-AP'), '$[*]'), '$',
       JSON_EXTRACT((SELECT concat('[',
                      group_concat(
                       JSON_OBJECT('ARouter'   , `ARouter`,
                                   'AInterface', `AInterface`,
                                   'BRouter'   , `BRouter`,
                                   'BInterface', `BInterface`)
                                   SEPARATOR  ','),
                                   ']') 
                       FROM netplan.LinksPACSLcl
                      WHERE ARouter = 'PE23-SNG-AP'
                         OR Brouter = 'PE23-SNG-AP'), '$[*]'));
```

If you use sql server, you can use `SELECT ... FOR XML RAW...`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/example-specifying-a-root-element-for-the-xml-generated-by-for-xml